# Use Conditional Random Field (CRF) to predict the stock price of the next time stamp

Tags: regression, machine-learning, prediction, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I have a dataset consist of twitter sentiment score at any past time stamp t for a stock $s$, denoted as $\{x_{s,0}, x_{s,1}, ..., x_{s,t-1}\}$. Also, I know the corresponding stock price $\{y_{s,0}, y_{s,1}, ..., y_{s,t-1}\}$.

I want to use these data to train a prediction model. Given the sentiment of the past $n$ days $\{x_{s,t-n+1}, ..., x_{s,t-1}\}$, the price of the stock of the past $n$ days $\{y_{s,t-n+1}, ..., y_{s,t-1}\}$ and the sentiment score of the stock today $x_{s,t}$, the model can predict the price of the stock today $y_{s,t}$.

My questions:

1. I hypothesize that today's price depends on today's sentiment $x_{s,t}$ and yesterday's price $y_{s,t-1}$. In this case, can I use continuous conditional random field (CRF)?

[image]

My concern is that CRF, as used in POS tagging, usually generates the whole sequence **Y**. But here, the past status and observation are all available. I just want the status of the next step. I know it is doable. But does CRF overkill the problem?

2. It seems that basic time series or regression can take care of the problem, by taking $y_{s, t-1}$ and $x_t$ as explanatory variables. Am I right? If yes, what is the difference? What is the advantage of CRF?

Comment: This is an example of butcher a chicken with a ox knife (you know that expression). Totally overkill....